# Wait in Python Selenium with page object model not working

Tags: python, selenium

I have this Login page to enter username password and click on Login button (this is my code) :

```
    def enter_username(self):
    # Click on Email field
    self.find_element(*self.locator.email_field).click()
    # Clear Email field
    self.find_element(*self.locator.email_field).clear()
    # Tape Email
    self.find_element(*self.locator.email_field).send_keys(user1_email)

def enter_password(self):
    # Click on Password field
    self.find_element(*self.locator.password_field).click()
    # Clear Password field
    self.find_element(*self.locator.password_field).clear()
    # Tape Password
    self.find_element(*self.locator.password_field).send_keys(user1_password)

def click_login(self):
    # Click on the user menu
    self.find_element(*self.locator.login_button).click()
```

I use this locators class contain ID's :

```
class LoginPageLocators(object):

email_field = (By.XPATH,'//*[@id="sCourriel"]')
password_field = (By.XPATH,'//*[@id="sPassword"]')
login_button = (By.NAME,'loginBTN')
```

And i use this base page :

```
class Page(object):
def __init__(self, driver, base_url=uat_qa_url):
    self.base_url = base_url
    self.driver = driver
    self.timeout = 30

def find_element(self, *locator):
    return self.driver.find_element(*locator)

def open(self, url):
    url = self.base_url + url
    self.driver.get(url)

def get_title(self):
    return self.driver.title

def get_url(self):
    return self.driver.current_url

def hover(self, *locator):
    element = self.find_element(*locator)
    hover = ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(element)
    hover.perform()
```

My test case :

```
    def test_consultation_CCI_WBA_001(self):
    loginPage = LoginPage.Loginpage(self.driver)
    consultationPage = ConsultationsPage.Consultationspage(self.driver)
    homePage = HomePage.Homepage(self.driver)

    # Test case CCI_WBA_001 (Créer une consultation avec les informations nécessaires)

    # Login ass admin
    loginPage.enter_username()
    time.sleep(5)
    loginPage.enter_password()
    time.sleep(5)
    loginPage.click_login()
    time.sleep(5)
```

My question : how i can eliminate time.sleep or how i can use wait for element present?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options.

1) Implicit wait: It will make sure the driver wait for specified time for element when you have below line of code.

```
driver.implicitly_wait('10')
```

2) Explicit Wait: you can wait for the element to be present explicitly using the below.

**Imports needed:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Code:**

```
def enter_username(self):
    # wait for the email element (update the location strategy based on your condition)
    email = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.id("id goes here"))))
    # Clear Email field
    email.clear()
    # Tape Email
    email.send_keys(user1_email)
```

Comment: But how i can use my locators page, its contain more than 100 id (xpath, name, id)?

Comment: How i can use def hover

Comment: now i have this error :
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute

Comment: I got the same "'bytes' object has no attribute" error after I let Pycharm resolve my imports and it grabbed EC from telnetlib. Make sure the imports are what is in the answer.